# Помощь с def, аргументами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как мне реализовать возможность вызова конкретного аргумента
пример

`func (1, test_arg = 'привет мир')`

И как проверить, что человек введет в `test_arg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Создайте *другую* функцию, например

   ```
   def func_1(test_arg='привет мир'):
       return func(1, test_arg=test_arg)
   ```

   и предложите юзеру, чтобы вызывал эту функцию (`func_1`).
2. Что ввели в `test_arg`, будет просто в переменной `test_arg`, например

   ```
   def func(number, test_arg='привет мир'):
       print(test_arg)
   ```